# Which way is better to load models in magento?

Tags: magento, collections, magento-1.7

I don't know if i am asking that right.I need to load a product, change some values and save it. My question is which way is the appropriate to do it.Currently i am using that way:

```
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

1) In general it works fine even with 40K products.But i read that this way is leading to memory leak? Also for that solution i read that if i disable the reindex functionality i can improve the process time.

2) If i use another way and load it as a collection and then apply some filters, ex `addFieldToFilter('sku',$the_product_i_want)` 
would be better?

When i say better i mean: 1)the magento way, 2)time efficient 3)not doing something that i don't need to do.

Comment: I'd say you seem to be mixing the concepts. addFieldToFilter - is about collections. Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load() - is about models. I assume the "correct" form of your question would be - whats the best: 1)first to load ALL products from db and then filter those you need to process by the means of php 2) filter the needed products by the means of mysql (which is addFieldToFilter does) and then update ALL loaded products, then the answer is 2nd option.

Comment: if i do that: Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load() i load ALL the products?Because i call the model product?even if i use the id to load one product?Sorry about my questions but i am trying to understand Magento better. @Rob

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, model->load() is the method which loads model. "Model" concepts is roughly saying like a single instance of the data structure. I.e. product is the data structure, and when you call ->load($id) you populate that structure by data take from the db by given $id. While addFieldToFilter is something applied to collections, not models. Collection concept - is a set of products, taken from DB by a single request (in most cases. In general collection is abstract meaning a set of single instances). So when you do ->addFieldToFilter, you add condition to your collections' request

Comment: So for my case of loading products, making some changes and then save them back,which solution is the best? if we can say that..

Comment: hm... well In general if you have a huge DB  better look at MAGMI as it uses direct Sql quieries for data modification which is the fastest way ever. Magento code - is wrapper around it. If you go  MAGMI http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API

Comment: but if you need a generic way - you can do $product->setData('attribute_code', 'your data...') and then just save product,that's all. A simple logic scenario

Answer (score 5):

Each time you call the following code snippet `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` Magento will create a new model object in the memory. And that will lead to memory wastage. You can do as follows.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$id = $model->getIdBySku($sku);
$product = $model->load($id);
```

At the same time `if you have the product object` you can use the following code.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$product = $collection->addFieldToFilter('sku',$the_product_i_want);
```

Comment: To be precise, this doesn't lead to classical memory leakage like you might find in C, but it can lead to high memory usage.

Comment: @siliconrockstar : thanks, you are correct, I modified the answer